# Find jobs which use a database connection

Tags: talend

Anyone know a quick way to find out all jobs which use a database connection in Talend?

For example, if I have a Database connection "DB_Run_Prod01" defined in Talend. I want to identify all the jobs which access this connection so that I can recompile them if I make a change to DB_Run_Prod01. Any ideas?

I'm using Talend Open Studio on Windows 7.

Thanks in advance,
Bee

Comment: every talend job is saved as .item+other files in your workspace folder under process directory. so either you can search using any file editor in this direcotry for your string or you can user talend job to read all these .item files - these are xml structures and you can parse this in this talend job to search for your required string. if you open any .item file you will be able to understand what it contains and where to search..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

every talend job is saved as .item+other files in your workspace folder under process directory. so either you can search using any file editor in this direcotry for your string or you can user talend job to read all these .item files - these are xml structures and you can parse this in this talend job to search for your required string. if you open any .item file you will be able to understand what it contains and where to search.